# Is it possible to create my own event listener in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, event-listener

First of all I should mention that I am at the very starting point of learning practical JavaScript programming, so I thought that modifying a website's appearance in Google Chrome which I everyday refer to might be a good engagement point.

I searched the term "create you own event listener in google chrome" in google and all of first results were somehow relating to "How you can see google chrome's own event listeners".

So I wanted to get an answer from those who are professional.

Answer (score 0):

After searching more on the net I realized that it is possible to do so by making **Userscript**s.